# Split second blue screen flashes

Tags: samsung

I get flashes of the blue screen when opening or watching videos or when  i open apps. It's only a split second but doesn't seem right and have never had this happen before. I think happens when I play Spotify also. Somethings up and just wondered if anyone has had this happen . I have the samsung tab e.

Answer (score 0):

Try resetting application cache, it will take a few minutes but, this can most likely not being fixed even with factory reset, as it seems to an **production issue**.

Answer (score 0):

I received a Galaxy Tab A as a present, had blue flashing when google browser home page opened. Returned for new one, same issue. Tried full factory reset and data wipe, opening in safe mode, all to no effect. Samsung on-line chat support could not help. Recommend it be sent to Samsung service depot.